# Debugger cannot access memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb

This looks like a common issue but I did not manage to understand why it fails. I received a C code that initializes a handle structure somewhere and is passed as a parameter in the function :

```
static int32 my_function(const type_st *struct_handle)
```

There a static variable on top of the code defined as intermediate variable to cast memory chunk :

```
static type_st (*my_structure[nb_entries])
```

In my_function :

```
 my_structure = (type_st (*)[nb_entries])struct_handle->param_list
```

The GDB debugger cannot access memory for

> (*my_structure)[x].y

(whatever x and y parameters).

There is no error when doing a memset over that structure but I cannot read the values with the debuger.
Can someone explain me what is wrong ?

Comment: What happens when you just try ``my_structure``, then ``*my_structure`` and build it up until it no longer works?

Comment: Can you access the array from the calling code? Is the address of the array in the calling code the same as the adress recieved in the function?

Comment: Since `.` binds more tightly than `*`, maybe instead of `*my_structure[x].y` you want `(*my_structure[x]).y` or `my_structure[x]->y`.

Comment: provide some [MCVE] please. Without it, your question is unclear. Perhaps `my_structure`, `x` and/or `y` have wrong values. But trust both the compiler and the debugger (they are very probably much more tested and much less buggy than your own code).